# Intervention / Image Image source not readable

Tags: laravel, intervention

I have tried to solve the problem by looking at the answers for the same problem, but their answer didnt' solve my problem

I have this error when i run this:

```
$image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
```

when I dd the path, this is wht i have:

"C:\Users\USER\MziSpoort\public\storage/uploads/V9SGmLlbg0r21h7y3pVT6w2IvJwQhTD6nkDtvAYO.jpeg"

thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = $request->file('image');
        $slug = str_slug($request->title);
        if (isset($image))
        {
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());   
            $image_resize->resize(1600,1066);
            if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/post'))
            {
                mkdir('storage/uploads/post',0777,true);
            }
            //$image->move('storage/uploads/post',$imagename);
            $image_resize->save('storage/uploads/post/'.$imagename);
        }else{
            $imagename = "default.png";
        }

// just use this code, i hope your problem solve
```